# MS Access ListBox Selected item

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, listbox

How can I make a listbox in access display a certain value of the list?

Assumtion: I want to display “Alex”

Listbox value are the following:

```
ID           Name
1             Tom
2             Peter
3             Alex
4             Susanne
```

Normally it works with

```
Forms("Trade").Controls("Erfassung").Column(0) = 3   Listbox shows “3, Alex”
```

But using ADODB.Connection to fill the listbox its not working anymore.

```
Dim DBSQL As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RSSQL As New ADODB.Recordset

DBSQL.ConnectionString = CONSTRING
DBSQL.Open


SQL = "SELECT [ID], [Name] FROM [Clients] ORDER BY [Name] ASC; "
RSSQL.Open SQL, DBSQL, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
Set Forms!Trade.Erfassung_Client.Recordset = RSSQL
RSSQL.Close


Forms("Trade").Controls("Erfassung").Column(0)  -> results in runtime error 451
Forms("Trade").Controls("Erfassung").value = 3 -> Listbox shows “4, Susanne” because Susanne is the 3rd value in the sorted List
```

How can I make the listbox display “3, Alex” ? (without the workaround figuring out which position Alex is)

Answer (score 1):

If it is bound to the first column (and it should), then set its `Value` property:

```
Me!Erfassung.Value = 3
```

or, if from outside:

```
Forms!Trade!Erfassung.Value = 3
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution. It does not work, the listbox is filled with the record set. But there appear no selected value (3 e.g.)

Comment: Then it is not bound to the first column. This is so basic - it cannot fail unless something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If using ADODB to add items to a listbox, the listbox itself needs to be set to "Value List". Please refer to Microsoft's [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.listbox.additem)

As Gustav mentioned, you just do

```
Me!Erfassung.Value = "Alex"
```

Also don't forget that listboxes are zero-indexed.